# Can I use a limit of places when using google places api web service?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

When using google places web service api to retrieve places close to a location according several conditions (like type=restaurant), apart from the radius, is there any way to limit the number of places I receive? Because I'm only interested in the closest place (nearby).
I don't see in the docs anything related to that.
Thanks.

Comment: You mean something like [this (finds places within 10 minute drive of entered address using the directionsMatrix)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveG.html?q=coffee&address=manhattan)?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean, when sending the network request, doing something like LIMIT 1, which means not returning more than 1 place. Like SQL.

Comment: Read the documentation.  If it is supported it will be listed.

Comment: It doesn't say anything, which is a pity.

Comment: That would mean it isn't supported.